# Format a String to a Fixed Date at UTC+0 in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, java-8

I want to convert a String date - `2017-01-01` to `java.util.Date` with `UTC+0`. So, what I am expecting is.

> `"2017-01-01" -> 2017-01-01T00:00:00 UTC+0100`

Here is how I am trying to do, but as my default Timezone is UTC+1, I am getting that 1 hour added to the Date.

```
Date d = Date.from(Instant.parse("2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"));

SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss 'UTC'ZZZZZ");

String output = sf.format(d);

System.out.println(output);
```

Here is the output:

```
2017-01-01T01:00:00 UTC+0100
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Set the timezone on the `SimpleDateFormat` to UTC before you call `sf.format(d);`. Note that `Date` objects do not contain timezone info - they are just a number of millis since 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 UTC. Your `Date` object itself doesn't know it's in UTC. Also: Why are you mixing the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` API with the new `java.time` API? Use `java.time`, not the old API.

Comment: Aaaah. Yes, you are right. So stupid of me.

Comment: This isn’t what you asked, but allow me to mention anyway: the risk of confusion is a lot smaller with the newer Java data and time API. Consider using `LocalDate` for your date and you will be freed from bothering about hours or time zone or anything.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the timezone first and then format it.

```
sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = sf.parse(d);
```

And now format as per your requirements:

```
String output = sf.format(date);
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is mixing oldfashioned and modern classes. `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated. `Instant` is modern (from 2014). I recommend you stick to the modern ones unless you are working with an old API that requires and/or gives you an instance of an oldfashioned class. So the answer is

```
    String output = LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01")
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.ofHours(1))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss 'UTC'XX"));
```

The result is the one you asked for

```
2017-01-01T00:00:00 UTC+0100
```

The code is not really shorter than yours, but once you get used to the fluent style you will find it clearer and more natural. The room for confusion and errors is considerably reduced.

If you want the start of day in whatever time zone the user is in, just fill in `ZoneId.systemDefault()` instead of `ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)`.

`LocalDate` parses your date string — `"2017-01-01"` — without an explicit format. The string conforms to ISO 8601, and the modern classes use this standard as their default for parsing and also for their `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder please try this also:

```
Date date = new Date();
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
date = cal.getTime();
```